# Recommended way to import web components in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, polymer

Google's [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) relies on HTML imports like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
```

Right now I'm keeping all the custom web components in the static folder and loading them like this:

template.html

```
<link rel="import" href="{% static 'polymer/my-custom-element.html' %}">
```

In the web component I import things using paths relative to the file:

my-custom-element.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Is this the recommended way to import web components when using Django or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use absolute path where possible.
Also I advice you use django-bower. It can handle bower statics in best way.

Answer (score 0):

Use django-bower (https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower), importing its also bit tricky cause 'static' in django template will add all import url pattern, for example yours import url it must be

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer.html">
```